# I'm trying to get info from sheet 2 onto sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a complexed workbook that im trying to take info from one of the sheets and put into a new sheet by using the IF function or VLOOKUP but i cant seem to get it to work.

Example:

*Sheet 1:*
**I have empty cells from B14:B47 and empty cells in C14:C47**

*Sheet 2:*
**I have Names in cells from C13:C84 all in alphabetical order, (none are the same).**

**Empty cells in H13:H84**

***The sheet is to show how many hours people will be working in that area***

I want to input an amount of hours into a cell on sheet 2 inbetween the H13:H84 and for sheet 1 to pick up the amount of hours and place it into C14:C47, at he top as a list (there wont be a full list) and for the matching names on their rows in sheet 2 to be picked up and placed into B14:B47, aswell at the top of the list.

So to clarify:
**Joe Bloggs is in C14 on sheet 2**
he has worked 8 hours and i will input this into the cell next to his name H14,

I want sheet 1 to pick up that his name has a number next to it and place his name in a B14 on sheet 1 and his hours in C14 on sheet 1 and anybody else in this bracket and range.

I hope this makes sense as ive been at this hours. :-)

Comment: So are you basically trying to make a summary page of only people who have hours next to their names? So, if Joe Bloggs didn't have a number next to his name he wouldn't appear at all on sheet 1?

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy Sheet2(C:C) to Sheet1(B:B) and Sheet2(H:H) to Sheet1(C:C) ?
It´s not clear, as @sr28 said, if you want to ignore empty cells...

If you want just to copy, use:

```
Sub copyData()

Dim Count As Integer

Count = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row  'find last row from column C on sheet2
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

For i = 1 To Count
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 3)
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 8)
Next i

End Sub
```

If you want to ignore blank cells on Sheet2.H, you can use:

```
Sub copyDataNoEmpty()

Dim Count As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Count = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row  

j = 1
For i = 1 To Count
    If Sheet2.Cells(i, 8) <> Empty Then
        Sheet1.Cells(j, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 3)
        Sheet1.Cells(j, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 8)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```